# prove $a^b+b^c+c^a\le a^2+b^2+c^2$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c>0$ and such $a+b+c=3$,show that
$$a^b+b^c+c^a\le a^2+b^2+c^2$$I have tried
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\ge\dfrac{1}{3}(a+b+c)^2=3$$
but I am stuck here. How could I continue this proof?

Comment: It doesn't seems true to me , put $a=3,b=4,c=5$ and you the the RHS will become $50$ and LHS is clearly greater than it , contradicting your question, Is there any typo?

Comment: @AtulMishra Yes, but $a+b+c$ must be $3$, as the OP added in the question.

Comment: yes @Nilknarf I missed that part

Comment: Here's a hint: you want to make sure that minimum of $f(a,b) = a^2+b^2+(3-a-b)^2 - a^b-b^{3-a-b}-(3-a-b)^a \geq 0$. By showing that $f$ only has one minimum for all $0\leq b\leq 3$ (it appears so from a graph) and that the minimum of $f$ is $\geq 0$ for all $b$, the problem is solved. This means showing that $df\over da$ only has one root, at say, $a_{min@b}$, and $f(a_{min@b},b) \geq 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Put $x = \dfrac{a}{3}, y = \dfrac{b}{3}, z = \dfrac{c}{3} \implies x+y+z = 1$, and $x, y, z > 0$. Thus we can write, for example: $a^b = (a^{b/3})^3 = (a^3)^{b/3} = (a^3)^y, b^c = (b^{c/3})^3 = (b^3)^{c/3} = (b^3)^{z}, c^a = (c^{a/3})^3 = (c^3)^{a/3} = (c^3)^x$. Thus using the Weight AM-GM inequality: $a^b+b^c+c^a= (a^3)^y + (b^3)^z + (c^3)^x = (a^3)^y\cdot 1^x\cdot 1^z+ (b^3)^z\cdot 1^x\cdot 1^y+(c^3)^x\cdot 1^y\cdot 1^z \le ya^3+1x+1z+zb^3+1x+1y+xc^3+1y+1z= 2(x+y+z)+y(3x)^3+ z(3y)^3+x(3z)^3= 2+27(x^3y+y^3z+z^3x)\le 9(x^2+y^2+z^2)$. This inequality can be proven by a combination of Muirhead, Schur, Homogenizing, etc..I am sure it can be done. Proving this inequality is much better and one can see that the equality occurs precisely at $x = y = z = \dfrac{1}{3} \implies a = b = c = 1$ which is where the equality of the original variables $a,b,c$ occurs. I am sure this will motivate other users to step up and finish it.